# How to use fullpagejs with selectors Angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript, fullpage.js

I am making an Angular 7 project with fullpagejs Alvarotrigo and I have managed to make it work but I cannot see my website content because the color of fullpagejs is cover them all. If I use normal content in there it really shows up.

***Work normally***

```
  <div id="fullpage">
   <div class="section">Section 1</div>
   <div class="section">
    <div class="slide" data-anchor="slide1">Slide 2.1</div>
    <div class="slide" data-anchor="slide2">Slide 2.2</div>
   </div>
   <div class="section">Section 3</div>
   <div class="section">Section 4</div>
   </div>
```

***It not showing the content when I try to use selector from another components***

```
<div id="fullpage">
<div class="section">
    <c:home-header-section></c:home-header-section>
</div>
<div class="section">
    <c:our-story-section></c:our-story-section>
</div>
<div class="section">
    <c:our-business-section></c:our-business-section>
</div>
<div class="section">
    <c:our-partner-section></c:our-partner-section>
</div>
<c:footer-section></c:footer-section>
```

It's show only the color of background and content is behind them when I try to inspect them.
I was not sure what to do. Any ideas, Thanks.!

Comment: Are you using the official component for Angular? [angular-fullpage](https://alvarotrigo.com/angular-fullpage/)?

If so, you can see a demo of it on  the demo folder:
https://github.com/alvarotrigo/angular-fullpage/tree/master/demo

Answer (score 0):

There might be a structural directive such as *ngIf or *ngFor inside the your components.

In this case you could use this example "Dynamic Change"

https://github.com/alvarotrigo/angular-fullpage#dynamic-changes